# Polymorphism in C# generic types

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Why can't generics be used like this? Declare common open type or interface and separate logic for each concrete type directly:

```
interface IOpen<T>
{
    T A { get; }
}

class Concrete<int> : IOpen<int>
{
    public int A => 42;
    public string B => "42";
}

interface IWorker<T>
{
    void Do(IOpen<T> item);
}

class WorkerInt : IWorker<int>
{
    public void Do(Concrete<int> item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.A);
        Console.WriteLine(item.B);
    }
}
```

How to avoid that restriction in the code above? If I create class `ConcreteInt : IOpen<int>` then `WorkerInt` would not implement `IWorker<T>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define `class Concrete<int>` with `<int>` - it's like you're trying to override the normal definition of `int` with a new generic type called `int`. But then in the class you're trying to actually return an `int`.

So it should look like:

```
class Concrete : IOpen<int>
{
    public int A => 42;
    public string B => "42";
}
```

But now the class `WorkerInt` would have to look like this:

```
class WorkerInt : IWorker<int>
{
    public void Do(Concrete item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.A);
        Console.WriteLine(item.B);
    }
}
```

But `IWorker<int>` must implement `void Do(IOpen<T> item)` and even though `Concrete` implements `IOpen<T>` you can't use `void Do(Concrete item)` because it is more restrictive than `void Do(IOpen<T> item)`.

So you must define it this way:

```
class WorkerInt : IWorker<int>
{
    public void Do(IOpen<int> item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.A);
        //Console.WriteLine(item.B);
    }
}
```

But that makes `item.B` no longer work as `IOpen<int>` doesn't have a `B` property.

The only way to make this work is to change `IWorker` to be this:

```
interface IWorker<T, R> where T : IOpen<R>
{
    void Do(T item);
}
```

Then `WorkerInt` can be this:

```
class WorkerInt : IWorker<Concrete, int>
{
    public void Do(Concrete item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.A);
        Console.WriteLine(item.B);
    }
}
```

Comment: `interface IWorker<T, R> where T : IOpen<R>` looks like a magic trick and it works without serious code changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't meant as a placeholder for type inference. Generics are meant to allow containers like `List`, `Dictionary`, `Tree`, etc. to contain any type without needing to cast to and from `Object`. They make containers more statically robust.

If you want to be able to pass a limited set of types to some kind of processor, then use overloaded methods.

```
public void Do(int item) { ... }

public void Do(string item) { ... }
```

This way, the method signature is what determines which method to use.

Additionally, if you're trying to make different worker objects, you could have a similar set of static overloaded methods that instantiate the workers and call the `Do()` method.

```
class WorkerManager {
    public static void DoWork(int item) {
        var worker = new WorkerInt();
        worker.Do(item);
    }

    public static void DoWork(string item) {
        var worker = new WorkerString();
        worker.Do(item);
    }
}
```